# PYTHON Release upgrade

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a python code on 3.6.3 release version in my project to monitor the system and other application performance.

I found python is releasing bug fixes for every 3-6 months.

How can I keep my python release up to date in my project?

Should I uninstall 3.6.3 and re-install 3.6.4 or any command utility to upgrade it to 3.6.4 without uninstalling existing release?

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Windows 2012 R2